# How to encode a list name for REST in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, rest, url, encoding

I created a list in the `en` site called

```
hello's~`!@#$%^&*(){}[]:;"'<>?/\|*-+.
```

What I am trying to do is figure out what exactly is the encoded version of the name if I am trying to target it by name in a REST url. I have this

```
http://mysite/en/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('hello's~`!@#$%^&*(){}[]:;"'<>?/\|*-+.')
```

but this doesn't work of course. I tried url encoding it to

```
http://mysite/en/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('hello%27s~%60!%40%23%24%25%5E%26*()%7B%7D%5B%5D%3A%3B%22%27%3C%3E%3F%2F%5C%7C*-%2B.')
```

but even then, doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: I think you have not encoded that last `.`.  But still wondering why such an odd name :).

Comment: I just want to figure out a way to make sure that no matter what the user types for a name of a list, then I will be able to target it with rest, so this is just an extreme test basically.

Comment: Cool try this `hello%27s%7E%60%21%40%23%24%25%5E%26%28%29%7B%7D%5B%5D%3A%3B%22%27%3C%3E%3F%2F%5C%7C-%2B.`

Comment: it says invalid url.

Comment: hi omega, am just curious to know why did you create a list with that name?

Comment: It's just a test....

Answer (score 7):

Try using `encodeURIComponent` to encode the list title. However, `encodeURIComponent` does not encode apostrophe. For apostrophes use `%27` twice or two apostrophes `''`. See this for more detail: http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2012/06/special-characters-in-rest-query-filter.html